Jenkins pipeline issue when deploying to kubernetes
I am working on a pipeline to deploy a container image to kubernetes cluster on GCP.
I get a very long error message without a lot of detail as to what the issue is. This is a small piece of message from console output:
stage('Deploying to Kubernetes') 
{
steps {
script {
kubernetesDeploy(configs: 'deployment.yml', 'service.yml')
}
}
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: c73bf02e-d54b-4f0c-96db-582cb66a5a0c
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'kubernetesDeploy' found among steps [ansibleAdhoc, ansiblePlaybook, ansibleVault, approveReceivedEvent, approveRequestedEvent, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, container, containerLog, createEvent, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findBuildScans, getContext, git, input, isUnix, junit, kubernetesApply, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, podTemplate, powershell, properties, publishChecks, pwd, pwsh, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstable, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitForBuild,
Have all Kubernetes plugins installed

First, make sure that the Kubernetes Continuous Deploy plugin is installed. If the plugin is installed then my guess is that kubernetesDeploy is being called in the wrong place. Try moving it out of the script block and into the steps.  According to the doc:

The kubernetes-cd plugin provides function kubernetesDeploy for Jenkins Pipeline support. You can go to the Snippet Generator page under Pipeline Syntax section in Jenkins, select "kubernetesDeploy: Deploy to Kubernetes" from the "Sample Step" dropdown, and it will provide you configuration interface for the plugin. After filling the entries and click "Generate Pipeline Script" button, you will get the sample scripts which can be used in your Pipeline definition.

So use this to generate a sample and ensure that your kubernetesDeploy block matches this sample.
If all attempts fail, consider using regular kubectl commands.

I do have the plug in installed.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled. It appears that the kubernetesDeploy has been depricated. When I try to add credentials, under kind, kubernetes deployment does not exist.

Best to use kubectl
